# How do I manually register ASP.NET MVC controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC app starts very very slowly (minimum 20 seconds till first render). It has *lots* of assemblies in the bin folder.

I understand the runtime scans all assemblies, looking for `Controller` classes. I imagine this kind of reflection would be very slow. We're on shared hosting, so the first load is terribly slow, and there are lots of first loads, because the app pool is recycled frequently.

I've seen lots of examples of manually registering controllers using IOC containers. We don't use IOC.

*So, how do I manually register controllers?* I'd like to do this in `Application_Start`, or something like that.

**Edit** regarding some of the comments. I know that this won't solve the slow start problem entirely. But it might help. So no point in dissuading me from trying, because we've decided to try :).

Comment: I highly doubt the bottleneck is in identifing all the controller classes

Comment: @ScottSelby Won't know until I try. Reflection over dozens of assemblies is bound to be slow.

Comment: just remove all controllers from the app except Home , build and push .  There shouldn't be anything dependent on those being there , and that should be a quick test - see if things dramatically improve, guessing they wont.

Comment: @ScottSelby Nice idea! We plan on manual registration anyways though, due to some profiling we've done. Before my code is even reached, the runtime drops about 10s, and I have no clue on what... I'm hoping manual registration of controllers and views will help.

Comment: Compiling razor views, generating bundles, ngenning .NET assemblies, initializing ORM(depending on the ORM) are other contributors to "first run" slowness and there are various techniques to mitigate these. **Is this a concern because you want to reduce first access time in development?  Or in production?**

Comment: @AaronLS We already precompile views using RazorGenerator. We want to reduce first load time in production.

Comment: I don't know if it can help (I never test that :-) ). Try to compile all your assemblies into one by using ILMerge http://martycodes.blogspot.fr/2011/05/c-ilmerge.html

Comment: @CodeNotFound Nice idea, but it seems far quicker and easier to just manually register controllers, I'm sure there is a straightforward way.

Comment: How did you know that the problem is related to the controllers registration ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I don't. It's just a good guess. We've optimized other things such as ORM (EntityFramework), Razor views, etc. So now we're trying this.

Comment: It might help the question if you create a simple `[HttpGet] public IHttpActionResult Poke() { return Ok(); }` and post the "time to first byte" which you can see in the Network tab in e.g. Chrome. That will tell you the minimum time to compile and run everything. Also remember that the very first time you run your web app things are slower. The db is initializing, the assemblies are loaded etc. This can be mitigated by simply having some computer run some requests every 12 hours or so.

Comment: Be very careful to "measure twice, cut once". You want to make sure you are solving the right problem. What if the problem has nothing to do with controller lookup. Then you'll be wasting the time you could be spending solving the _real_ problem.

Comment: @hbob I think it's a good question in general.  Have you tried the `namespaces` parameter of the `MapRoute` method?  This *might* improve performance if all your controllers are in the same namespace by reducing what must be scanned. That's pure speculation though.

Comment: @AaronLS No different namespaces, and we're using attribute routing.... Nice idea though.

Comment: @JohnSaunders You're right. Though I'm sure this isn't hard. The IOC examples give me the feeling that there is some straightforward way to do this, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @hbob FYI It let's you provide a list of namespaces, assuming its finite.

Comment: @Patrick We have something similar to that. First load takes 15-20s. And profiling indicates that other than datacontext intiialization (obviously!), all the time is spent doing init work by the runtime.

Comment: It may be easy. But, given a finite amount of time, it's best to spend your time where you'll be solving the actual problem. Also, any changes you make always run the risk of making things worse. It's best to start out by only making the changes necessary to solve the problem, or you may have _two_ problems to fix.

Comment: @JohnSaunders True words. But since we don't know where the problem is, we need to find it via a process of elimination. We started by precompiling views. That helped a lot. Then we optimized the ORM. That helped. Then we offloaded some stuff onto a lazy-loaded cache. That helped. Now we're optimizing controller registration. Not sure why so many here are opposed to trying :).

Comment: I recommend using profiling or some other such technique to find out what the problem actually is. Trial and error is not a good way to do things like this. You can quite easily find yourself solving the wrong problem. I say so because it has happened to me. I spent a week fixing a memory usage problem which was crashing IIS, only to find out that memory usage was not crashing IIS! It was something totally unrelated and unsuspected.

Comment: @JohnSaunders We did profile. The major time "wasted" (which is not ORM related) occurs in the runtime, before the request is even serviced. There's only so much I can optimise, so this seems like a good candidate.

Comment: is that when controller lookup occurs? Have you seen it scanning assemblies during this time? I mean, go ahead, but it sounds like you're skipping steps.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override [DefaultControllerFactory](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultControllerFactory.cs). Then set it at **Application_Start**.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof (CustomControllerFactory));
```

Example -

- [Understanding and Extending Controller Factory in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i)
- [Inside the ASP.NET MVC Controller Factory](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Inside-the-ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Factory.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC Controllers and Conventions](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asp.net-mvc-controllers-and-conventions/).

***FYI:***  Mark Seemann [(author of Dependency Injection in .Net)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) said  *"creating an object instance is something the .NET Framework does extremely fast. Any performance bottleneck your application may have will appear in other places."*